# Diferentes rutas con el mismo controlador y accion en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo varias rutas en `routes.rb` que van al mismo controlador y accion.

```
post 'ruta_1'   =>  'controlador#general'
post 'ruta_2'   =>  'controlador#general'
post 'ruta_3'   =>  'controlador#general'
post 'ruta_4'   =>  'controlador#general'
post 'ruta_5'   =>  'controlador#general'
```

Debe haber una forma mas elegantes de definir esto en el archivo de routes.

Comment: ¿Para qué necesitas diferentes rutas al mismo controlador/acción?, ¿el comportamiento es exactamente el mismo en todos los casos?

Comment: Cada ruta tiene un comportamiento similar, que se traduce en muchas acciones con codigo parecido, que a su vez se traduce en muchas lineas de codigo, asi que para simplificarlo, resumi todas las rutas en una accion y cada matiz de cada ruta la meti en una estructura CASE, logre bajar el controlador de mas de 3000 lineas en menos de 600 lineas y por supuesto se lee mucho mejor, el detalle es el archivo de routes que no se ve muy elegante.

Comment: Desconozco una forma más elegante para hacer lo que buscas, pero yo te recomendaría evaluar si realmente esa es la mejor solución. Si estás utilizando un _case_, mejor genera una acción para cada ruta, generalmente es mucho más claro usar acciones que un _case_.

Comment: Para _adelgazar_ tu controlador, yo recomendaría extraer lógica que tenga ajena a los controladores y pasarla a modelos o POROs (e.g. servicios); o bien, generar más controladores, dependiendo el caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personalmente, creo que lo que mencionas no es la forma en la cual deberían definirse las rutas. Una posible opción, donde deberías modificar las rutas, es usando [constraints](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints), algo como:

```
post 'ruta/:opcion' => 'controlador#general', constraints: { opcion: /[1-5]{1}/ }
```

donde rutas como `ruta/1` o  `ruta/5` serían válidas y  `ruta/0` o  `ruta/11` inválidas. Luego, manejar a nivel de controlador qué hacer en el `case` que mencionas dependiendo del valor de `params[:opcion]`.
Ahora, si cambiar las rutas no es una opción y de verdad necesitas disminuir las líneas de código, prueba con:

```
5.times { |i| post "ruta_#{i + 1}" => 'controlador#general' }
```

Ojo, que para que este cambio sea evaluado, deberás reiniciar tu rails server. Aparte siempre considera el factor "menos líneas de código" vs "entendimiendo del código". Creo que usando un loop en el archivo de routes, se aleja un poco de la "Rails way" que también podría interpretarse como un código que sea entendible por otros programadores que lleguen ahí y no solo por quien hizo el cambio.

---

En caso que uses [wildcards](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments), considera que una solución como `post 'ruta_(*any)'` podría aceptar como ruta válida cualquier cosa, incluido `ruta_1/otra/cosa/`, por lo tanto sería recomendable que la acompañes con constraints de lo que son tus valores válidos, algo como:

```
post 'ruta_(*any)' => 'controlador#general', constraints: { any: /[1-5]{1}/ }
```

Si pusiste rutas de 1 a 5 solo a modo de ejemplo y en realidad las restricciones son más complejas que eso, siempre [puedes usar un PORO donde definir tu lógica](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) para manejar las constraints.
Y en caso que ya tengas implementada lógica que maneje esa validación en la capa de controladores, considera mover la lógica y hacerlo de esta forma, ya que el verificar esto es tarea del enrutador y no debería alcanzar siquiera a llegar a la capa de controladores. Es un detalle que puede verse como menor, pero ayuda en la separación de responsabilidades y por tanto un mejor código.

Comment: Hace un par de horas encontre esto y camina, pero no se si se aleja de las convenciones de RoR:

```post 'ruta_(*any)'         =>  'controlador#general'```

Comment: @Developer no consideré wildcards ya que nunca he tenido la opción de usarlas antes, sin embargo revisa la última actualización a mi respuesta.